# Cómo crear el archivo JSON para el JSON Server (API REST FAKE)?

Tags: json, api, rest

Estoy haciendo un Api rest con Json server.

Mi duda: Necesito vincular la persona al checkin, solo que no se 
como crear el archivo Json para que la persona quede vinculada.
Debo hacer 2 archivos o puedo hacer todo en solo 1 archivo?
En caso de que sea solamente 1 archivo, como crear el archivo .json para el json server?

**Estructura del objeto persona**

```
{
“nome”: “Fulano”,
“document”: “87654343”,
“telefono”: “9999 6666”
}
```

**Estructura del checkin**

```
{
“pessoa”: objPessoa,
“fechaEntrada”: “2018-03-14T08:00:00”,
“fechaSaida”: “2018-03-16T10:17:00”,
“addlVeiculo”: true/false
}
```

Comment: Buenas. Por favor, traduce tu pregunta para evitar posibles cierres por idioma.En este caso estás en un stackoverflow en español.

Comment: Está traducido..... perdón, pense que estava en stack portugués.